# What happens if a petitioner is brought back to the Material Plane?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, planes, resurrection, soul, cosmology

A petitioner is, essentially, the soul of a deceased character that has found its way to the plane to which it belongs. However, as far as I am aware, it does retain its level and abilities - at least to a degree.

What would happen if a petitioner is subjected to the Plane Shift or similar spell - either by its own casting or otherwise - and, through that manner, brought back to the Material Plane? What would its type and/or statistics be? Would this at all be possible?

And would there be any consequences beyond pure mechanics to the petitioner in question? Consequences for the plane of origin and the arrival plane, for example?

Comment: This question may need a tag for its cosmology. That is, the last part seems kind of setting-dependent.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Petitioners can't leave their plane.

According to *Manual of the Planes*, p. 55, petitioners are bound to their plane and cannot be made to leave:

> *Planar Commitment*: Petitioners cannot leave the plane they inhabit. They are teleported one hundred miles in a random direction if an attempt is made to force them to leave.

Comment: I think one has to go on a road quest to convince whomever is in charge of the plane in question to release them... if one can pull that off....

Answer (score 3):

In the novel *Annihilation* from the [*War of the Spider Queen*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_of_the_Spider_Queen) series of novels, a halfling petitioner named [Dietr](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Dietr) manages to come back to the Prime Material Plane via a portal, but he becomes a [huecuva](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huecuva) as a consequence/punishment.